# Is it possible to have buffered bytes value as sharedprefference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, bytebuffer

Is it possible to having buffered bytes value in a sharedprefference? so it can be changed from a option activity could not find any answer on the internet or documentation about it.

```
            byte[] buf = new byte[5242880];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
                sfos.write(buf, 0, len);
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to having buffered bytes value in a sharedprefference?

No, other than by converting it to and from some string representation, then saving it as a string preference.

Note that storing 5242880 bytes, converted into a string, in a single element in an XML file (the backing store for `SharedPreferences`) is not a very good plan. Such a large buffer needs to be handled **very carefully** to prevent `OutOfMemoryErrors`, just as large `Bitmap` objects need to be handled very carefully.

Comment: iknow thats why i wanna have that setting in my developper settings so i can find out how much i can optimize my upload speed before running into a bufferowerflow